# Как получить изображение qr в байтах с библиотекой qrcode, или как я понял она умеет только сохранять? Тогда какие могут отдать байтами?

Tags: python, byte, qrcode

```
totp_auth = "ffghewrtf35rfgeht"
qrcode.make(totp_auth).save("qr_auth.png")
```

Методов которые отдают байты нет.
Так тоже нет, класс PIL не серилизуется в байты

```
b = bytes(qrcode.make(totp_auth))
```

Comment: но у вас ведь уже есть байты: `"ffghewrtf35rfgeht"`. зачем вам ещё какие-то библиотеки использовать для их «получения»?

Comment: @aleksandr-barakin Это строка, ее нужно закодировать в изображение qr и получить байты этого изображения

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33117447/2231972

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы можете создать буфер в который сохраните ваше изображение после чего сможете прочесть из него изображение в байтах.

```
import qrcode
import io

buf = io.BytesIO()
img = qrcode.make('Some data here')
img.save(buf)
buf.seek(0)
print(buf.read())  # b'\x89PNG\r\n\x1a\n\x00\x00\x00\rIHDR\x00\x00\x01"\x00\x00\x01"\x01\x00...'
```